# Raphael -- How to do rotation animation for grouped elements?

Tags: animation, set, raphael

(Raphael_2.01, WindowsXP, Firefox3.6)

I want to rotate grouped elements (5 elements). For example, using "set()":

```
var paper = Raphael("paper");
var set0 = paper.set();
for(var idx=0; idx<5; idx++){
set0.push(element);
}
```

Now I want to move (100, 100) and rotate (30 degrees) set0 by referring to [How is set animation done in Raphael?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279009/how-is-set-animation-done-in-raphael)

```
set0.animate({transform: "t100,100r30"}, 1000);
```

But it doesn't work. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

** Derived from http://groups.google.com/group/raphaeljs/browse_thread/thread/d59fea928cbd6322/40ef3c6d1bb8c515

*** But this hint isn't strictly correct. Because it lucks the space between '0.5' and cx.

The codes what I get are:

```
var cX = set0.getBBox().x + set0.getBBox().width/2;
var cY = set0.getBBox().y + set0.getBBox().height/2;
set0.animate({rotation:30 +' '+ cX + ' ' + cY}, 1000, ">");
```